# CloudKit + CoreData for many records over 100K

Tags: ios, performance, core-data, cloudkit

Now, I'm going to add iCloud Synchronization for my app. (CoreData + CloudKit settings)

But I'm struggling with the initial uploading/downloading steps for each device because of too many records. (over 100K)

**Fetching from CloudKit stops when the application goes into the background, so the user needs to stay in the foreground for a long time. (maybe longer than 1 hour)**

And I cannot find the methods to get the total download records to give download percentage status.

I already tried `NSPersistentCloudKitContainer`, but downloading was so slow and stopped at some time. (more than 1 days.. for testing 30K records)

So are there any common methods to deal with synchronizing 100K records at the initial step?

It might be:

- background fetching
- get the number of records to download at beginning of fetching.

Comment: Hi. Did you solve your problem? I am planning an app right now where I can run into the same problem.

Comment: How about you @m8xp0w3r, have you found a solution?

Comment: Hi @lorenzo. I did not see your comment. Sorry for that. Unfortunately I do not remember what I wanted to do last year, so no, I think I did not found a solution.